# Matlab: Pass Multiple Matrices Between Functions

Tags: matlab, matrix, syntax, pass-data

I’ve got a series of matrices

```
zeroingMatrix{i} % i going from 1 to 'matrixQuantity'
```

I need to pass these to another Callback function. So the idea was:

```
for i = 1:matrixQuantity
    setappdata(0, 'zeroingMatrix{'i '}', zeroingMatrix{i});
end
```

and get it back with:

```
for i = 1:matrixQuantity
    zeroingMatrix{i} = getappdata(0, 'zeroingMatrix{' i '}');
end
```

but apperantly this `'zeroingMatrix{'i '}'` is not the correct syntax and i can't figure out the right one. I tried all kinds of bracket combinationss but it won't let me do it.

When I try to start it, Matlab gives me the standard error:

> Error: File: RackReader.m Line: 184 Column: 36 Unexpected MATLAB
>   expression.

line 184 being the setappdata line.

This is not the only data I'm passing inbetween functions, but the first with a variable in it. Everything works fine exept this one.

Anyone else ever ran into this problem or has a better idea?

Thanks so much in advance

Mike

Comment: try using `num2str(i)` in the second parameter. So it looks `'zeroingMatrix{' num2str(i) '}'`

Comment: thx... You still need [ ] and you can't use { } i guess... but the rest works... thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your parameter name for `setappdata` has to just be a valid string and you're not able to construct that string using the syntax `'string'1'other'`. You would need to use `sprintf` or `num2str` to construct the string.

```
field = sprintf('zeroingMatrix{%d}', i);

% OR
field = ['zeroingMatrix{', num2str(i), '}'];
```

Also, a better approach would be to just store the *entire* cell array in there and index it after you retrieve it.

```
% Set the value
zeroingMatrix{i} = newval;
setappdata(0, 'zeroingMatrix', zeroingMatrix)

% Then later get the value
zeroingMatrix = getappdata(0, 'zeroingMatrix');
zeroingMatrix{i}
```

Answer (score 0):

So BlackAdder pushed me into the right direction:

```
for i = 1:matrixQuantity
    setappdata(0, ['zeroingMatrix' num2str(i)], zeroingMatrix{i});
end
```

and to get it back:

```
for i = 1:matrixQuantity
    zeroingMatrix{i} = getappdata(0, ['zeroingMatrix' num2str(i)]);
end
```

Comment: I would recommend storing the data in a single place rather than constantly altering the field that you save it under. See my approach below.